# Counting all possible functions $f: A \rightarrow B$, where $f(X) \supseteq Y$

Tags: combinatorics, functions, discrete-mathematics

I have function $f: A \rightarrow B$ and sets $X \subseteq A$ and $Y \subseteq B$. I need to compute the number of all possible functions $f$ where $f(X) \supseteq Y$.

I know that count of all possible functions where $f(X) \subseteq Y$ is $|Y|^{|X|}|B|^{|A|-|X|}$ . I think that solution is $|B|^{|X|}|B|^{|A|-|X|}$. Am I right?

Comment: It seems unlikely that the size of $Y$ doesn't matter. What is your argument?

Comment: @Henrik in $f(X)$ could be every element in $B$

Answer (score 1):

Your answer can't possibly be right, because it doesn't depend on what $Y$ is.  Clearly if you make $Y$ larger, the set of functions you're counting becomes smaller, so the answer must depend on $Y$.  In fact, your answer is just equal to $|B|^{|A|}$, which counts *all* functions $f:A\to B$, without any restriction that $f(X)\supseteq Y$.

I don't expect that there's any particularly simple answer to this question.  In the special case that $X=A$ and $Y=B$, you are counting surjections from $A$ to $B$, and this already requires a fairly complicated (and non-closed form) formula (see the answers to [Calculating the total number of surjective functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264799/calculating-the-total-number-of-surjective-functions)).

Comment: so I have two cases - if $X = A$ and $Y = B$ (than I counting all surjectiions), or $|X| < |A|$ and $|Y| < |B|$ ??

Comment: Assuming that the sets involved are finite, this question is a duplicate of [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2008572/get-number-of-functions-f-from-a-to-b-where-fx-supseteq-y-y-subseteq-b). I just posted an ugly answer to the earlier question.